# Jquery execute jquery script in loaded file

Tags: jquery, click

have a problem with this.
I've loaded a div from a other file with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#main_content" ).load( "/load-file.php #content" );
});
```

And in this loaded file is more jQuery:

```
    <div id="button"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#button").click function(){
                alert('clicked');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But this click function dont work, i dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, You have a typo

```
$("#button").click function(){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

It should be(a starting bracket after .click)

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

But you should try doing

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I tried to put it in the file where its loaded to and also in the other file, but it won't work.